# Nested loop is lwc js

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-web-components

I am facing a strange problem

I have the following piece of code :

```
    const allUpdatedFieldsIncludingAccount = event.detail.draftValues;
            var tempUpdatedList = [];                  
            for (var i = 0; i < allUpdatedFieldsIncludingAccount.length; i++) {  
                console.log(i+"allUpdatedFieldsIncludingAccount.length : "+allUpdatedFieldsIncludingAccount.length);
                let tempRecord = allUpdatedFieldsIncludingAccount[i]; 
                console.log("tempRecord ::  "+JSON.stringify(tempRecord));
                for (var i = 0; i < this.updatedAccountLookupList.length; i++) {
                    if(tempRecord['Id'] == this.updatedAccountLookupList[i].key){
                        tempRecord['AccountId'] = this.updatedAccountLookupList[i].value;
                    }
                }
                tempUpdatedList.push(tempRecord);
            }
```

Here allUpdatedFieldsIncludingAccount has a length of 2

updatedAccountLookupList also has a length of 2

My issue here is that, the first loop is running only once.

In the first console statement the  length of allUpdatedFieldsIncludingAccount  is printed as 2 and i value as 0.

But it still does not run when i value is equal to 1.

I am not getting any errors either.

Comment: try to use different names for the loops variables, for instance, `i` and `j`

Comment: Better yet, switch to using Array.forEach instead of index-based loops.

Comment: And stop using `var` because `let` and `const` are block scoped (what most people expect) and so better used instead; `var` is function scoped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use an IDE it will point out that you have declared the same variable, `i`, twice in the same function context. Variables defined via "var" have a scope of the function in which they are declared (or are "global" when defined outside a function). This is called hoisting. You can read more about this in a Salesforce context, [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/javascript-essentials-salesforce-developers/context-scope-closures). Because of that, both of your loops update the same variable and everything goes horribly wrong.

If the index in a "for loop" in JavaScript is only used to access the value from an array, you would be better off switching to use of [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) since this requires no local variable declaration and, using arrow functions, still gives you access to the same context (the containing function's closure).

Comment: That's exactly what is was. I totally missed that. Thank you so much.